# How to pipe to and read from the same tempfile handle without race conditions?

Tags: perl, pipe, temporary-files

Was debugging a perl script for the first time in my life and came over this:

```
$my_temp_file = File::Temp->tmpnam();
system("cmd $blah | cmd2 > $my_temp_file");
open(FIL, "$my_temp_file");
...
unlink $my_temp_file;
```

This works pretty much like I want, except the obvious race conditions in lines 1-3. Even if using proper tempfile() there is no way (I can think of) to ensure that the file streamed to at line 2 is the same opened at line 3. One solution might be pipes, but the errors during `cmd` might occur late because of limited pipe buffering, and that would complicate my error handling (I think).

How do I:

1. Write all output from `cmd $blah | cmd2` into a tempfile opened file handle?
2. Read the output without re-opening the file (risking race condition)?

Comment: Why use a file at all? Just capture the output by using backticks instead of `system`

Comment: @zdim, I think the OP is refering to the fact that someone could delete the file and create a new one between the first two stesp.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, that -- right, that makes sense as a concern.  (I wouldn't call that a race condition though, even though it'd indeed have to happen at _just_ the right time...)

Comment: Other than the options mentioned in comments and an answer (piped open and backticks), please note that there are excellent modules for handling external commands as well.

Comment: @zdim, I would call that a race condition :) If the Perl program wins the race against the attacker, everything's fine. But if the attacker wins the race, they might gain access to sensitive information

Comment: @zdim This is not the first time I played the "race condition" card and people argue "it is not". Another word for it would be "non-determinism", but I have a feeling that term is even less familiar to most. "Vulnerability" feels too generic. What would you call it? So that I can avoid future misunderstandings (my least favorite kind of understandings)

Comment: @Andreas My apology if my half-jokey comment caused contemplation; it's good to call it as you do. What triggered the remark was that the external messing with that file seemed kinda conjured, since no context for such concern is given; no threading, forking, other actors involved (that may want that file), etc. So do I show up and take the file? But of course, something -- _anything_ -- may well come along for the file in those microseconds and that's by all means a racing condition.

Comment: @Andreas ( Also, I wrote that just as I realized that you weren't concerned with `system`+`open` but with something else, unspecified and external to what's shown ... perhaps wrote it too loosely. (Even as it was a parenthetical remark:) )

Comment: @Andreas Another take. You say that a file to open may get changed right before it's opened ... well, sure, it may; but why would it? Nothing in the question gives one a reason to fear that. That's why we always `open ... or die $!;`, and that's that. It'd be hard if I always had to fear that a file may get changed under my feet. But, of course, the very fact that you ask about it means that there are reasons for concern. And once we need to look at that possibilty then there's a race condition.

Comment: @zdim No harm done my good sir/madame :-) Just want to improve communication from my end. I could indeed have been more clear on what the snippet is racing against, in this case another process with write permissions in the same (`/tmp`) directory. Thank you for your time and feedback.

Comment: That makes perfect sense then; specially with `/tmp`, which also may get cleared/cleaned up at any time.  One more comment, given some details in the question which now take on new light for me: you may want to look at `IPC::Run` for managing that external process (instead of `system`+`open`), the most powerful and rounded module for that job

Comment: @zdim, Re "*since no context for such concern is given*", There's a class of attacks that consists of substituting files or even mounted volumes to take advantage of such race conditions.

Comment: @ikegami Sure, what I was saying is that there was no hint stated in the question of what the specific concern would be.  So I wasn't sure what the OP had in mind, and at first I even thought that they confused how `open` works etc. But yes it's a legitimate concern, if they have grounds for such fears.

Comment: @zdim, I think File::Temp uses the pid in the file name? At the very least, it can.

Comment: @ikegami  That's how I often use it. One example: `($fh, $fname) = tempfile(DIR => ..., SUFFIX=>".progname.$$.tmp", UNLINK=>0);` (I need delete myself since there may be more than 1k such files in this program, what used to be over some limit). It can also return only `$fh` (but I dont know what it does internally then). It can be really safe for normal use, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

You can [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc#Using-open()-for-IPC) a pipe to a command and read its contents directly with no intermediate file:

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'cmd', $blah;

while( <$fh> ) {
    ...
    }
```

With short output, backticks might do the job, although in this case you have to be more careful to scrub the inputs so they aren't misinterpreted by the shell:

```
my $output = `cmd $blah`;
```

There are various modules on CPAN that handle this sort of thing, too.

### Some comments on temporary files

The comments mentioned race conditions, so I thought I'd write a few things for those wondering what people are talking about.

In the original code, Andreas uses [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp), a module from the Perl Standard Library. However, they use the `tmpnam` POSIX-like call, which has this caveat in the docs:

> Implementations of mktemp(), tmpnam(), and tempnam() are provided, but should be used with caution since they return only a filename that was valid when function was called, so cannot guarantee that the file will not exist by the time the caller opens the filename.

This is discouraged and was [removed for Perl v5.22's POSIX](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2017/09/dont-use-posix-to-create-temporary-files/).

That is, you get back the name of a file that does not exist yet. After you get the name, you don't know if that filename was made by another program. And, that `unlink` later can cause problems for one of the programs.

The "race condition" comes in when two programs that probably don't know about each other try to do the same thing as roughly the same time. Your program tries to make a temporary file named "foo", and so does some other program. They both might see at the same time that a file named "foo" does not exist, then try to create it. They both might succeed, and as they both write to it, they might interleave or overwrite the other's output. Then, one of those programs think it is done and calls `unlink`. Now the other program wonders what happened.

In the malicious exploit case, some bad actor knows a temporary file will show up, so it recognizes a new file and gets in there to read or write data.

But this can also happen within the same program. Two or more versions of the same program run at the same time and try to do the same thing. With randomized filenames, it is probably exceedingly rare that two running programs will choose the same name at the same time. However, we don't care how rare something is; we care how devastating the consequences are should it happen. And, rare is much more frequent than never.

#### File::Temp

Knowing all that, [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp) handles the details of ensuring that you get a filehandle:

```
my( $fh, $name ) = File::Temp->tempfile;
```

This uses a default template to create the name. When the filehandle goes out of scope, [File::Temp](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Temp) also cleans up the mess.

```
{
my( $fh, $name ) = File::Temp->tempfile;
print $fh ...;
...;
}  # file cleaned up
```

Some systems might automatically clean up temp files, although I haven't care about that in years. Typically is was a batch thing (say once a week).

I often go one step further by giving my temporary filenames a template, where the `X`s are literal characters the module recognizes and fills in with randomized characters:

```
my( $name, $fh ) = File::Temp->tempfile( 
    sprintf "$0-%d-XXXXXX", time );
```

I'm often doing this while I'm developing things so I can watch the program make the files (and in which order) and see what's in them. In production I probably want to obscure the source program name (`$0`) and the time; I don't want to make it easier to guess who's making which file.

#### A scratchpad

I can also open a temporary file with [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Using-undef-for-temporary-files) by not giving it a filename. This is useful when you want to collect outside the program. Opening it read-write means you can output some stuff then move around that file (we show a fixed-length record example in [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com)):

```
open(my $tmp, "+>", undef) or die ...

print $tmp "Some stuff\n";
seek $tmp, 0, 0;
my $line = <$tmp>;
```

Comment: It's `($fh, $filename) = File::Temp::tempfile();`.

Comment: Forgive me for noob question, but how (when?) do I get command status from `open my $fh, '-|', 'cmd', $blah; ...`?

Comment: @andreas: [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close) gives you the exit status.

Comment: Re "*[in the case of backticks] you have to be more careful to scrub the inputs so they are misinterpreted by the shell*", See `capturex` from core module IPC::System::Simple.

Answer (score 2):

File::Temp opens the temp file in `O_RDWR` mode so all you have to do is use that one file handle for both reading and writing, even from external programs.  The returned file handle is overloaded so that it stringifies to the temp file name so you can pass that to the external program.  If that is dangerous for your purpose you can get the `fileno()` and redirect to `/dev/fd/<fileno>` instead.

All you have to do is mind your `seek`s and `tell`s. `:-)`  Just remember to always set `autoflush`!

```perl
use File::Temp;
use Data::Dump;

$fh = File::Temp->new;
$fh->autoflush;

system "ls /tmp/*.txt >> $fh" and die $!;

@lines = <$fh>;
printf "%s\n\n", Data::Dump::pp(\@lines);

print $fh "How now brown cow\n";

seek $fh, 0, 0 or die $!;
@lines2 = <$fh>;
printf "%s\n", Data::Dump::pp(\@lines2);
```

Which prints

```perl
[
  "/tmp/cpan_htmlconvert_DPzx.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_htmlconvert_DunL.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_HfUe.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_XbD6.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_yzs9.txt\n",
]

[
  "/tmp/cpan_htmlconvert_DPzx.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_htmlconvert_DunL.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_HfUe.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_XbD6.txt\n",
  "/tmp/cpan_install_yzs9.txt\n",
  "How now brown cow\n",
]
```

HTH

Comment: I would never have guessed `>> $fh` to work. Mind blown.

Comment: Perl is just that awesome!  Try any of this in any other language.......

Comment: The ">> $fh" merely interpolates the `File::Temp` object, which stringifies to the file name. The interpolation might be cool, but beyond that, this is the same stuff you'd do in C. It's even the same function names.